# IIS7 Splash Page

Tags: http, iis-7, subdomain, cpanel

I have a subdomain at the address http://blog.wherelionsroam.co.uk/ but when i navigate to www.blog.wherelionsroam.co.uk (I know), it redirects me to a IIS7 splash page. Do I need to go into cpanel and install IIS7 tools in a certain directory to prevent this, or otherwise how do I fixed this?

Comment: you can't use www prefix on subdomain

Comment: is there any way of getting rid of the splash page then?

Comment: you could use the URL Rewrite module to rewrite the URL when you receive a request to www.blog.wherelionsroam.co.uk  to blog.wherelionsroam.co.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the root site (which will stop any response) or you can edit the bindings of the IIS site that is serving the subdomain to also respond to the WWW host header.

Comment: thank you, i presume i'll have to install the IIS manager for remote administration in W8?

Comment: Is this a hosted solution?  You should just be able to RDP to the box and make the changes in IIS manager.